# RoleManager.DeleteAsync or UpdateAsync not working as expected in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using asp.net core 2.0 Identity and I have an ApplicationRole class that inherits from IdentityRole. According documentation RoleManager manages CRUD operations about roles for AspNetRoles table, so service is added in Startup class:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication()
```

In configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

In my controller:

```
public AdministrationController(
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger,
            IStringLocalizer<AccountController> localizer)
{
   _roleManager = roleManager;
}
```

Controller operations:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Role_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ApplicationRoleViewModel role)
        {
            if (role != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationRole identityRole = new ApplicationRole();
                identityRole.Name = role.Name;

                if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(identityRole.Name))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Role", "Role already exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);
                }
            }

            return Json(new[] { role }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Role_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ApplicationRoleViewModel role)
        {
            if (role != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationRole identityRole = new ApplicationRole();
                identityRole.Id = role.Id;
                identityRole.Name = role.Name;
                await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(identityRole);
            }

            return Json(new[] { role }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Role_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ApplicationRoleViewModel role)
        {
            if (role != null)
            {
                ApplicationRole identityRole = new ApplicationRole();
                identityRole.Id = role.Id;
                identityRole.Name = role.Name;
                if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(identityRole.Name))
                {
                    await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(identityRole);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Role", "Role doesn't exist");
                }
            }

            return Json(new[] { role }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
```

_roleManager.CreateAsync method works as expected, role is inserted in AspNetRoles table, however _roleManager.UpdateAsync and _roleManager.DeleteAsync don't work as expected, table still shows same rows, not updated nor deleted.

Table rows before operations:

[image]

Update operation:

[image]

Delete operation:

[image]

After operations, table shows same rows as indicated in first screenshot. It's supposed RoleManager class manages operation to the table.

Comment: `UpdateRole` and `DeleteRole` perform some validation and will not throw on fail, instead they return an `IdentityResult` that may have some more information for you.  Try inspecting the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("Id,Role")] RoleViewModel pRole)
    {
        if (id != pRole.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(pRole.Id);
                role.Name = pRole.Role;
                var result = await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First().ToString());
                    return View();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return View(pRole);
    }
```

Comment: Although solution was found months ago, answer of Jason Caranzo is the right way of solving the issue, since to Update or Delete a role it's necessary to get the instance of the existing role data first from database by its id to be able to update or delete. Any entity object instance in EF seems to has its own id to connect it to the physical row table.